# ActiveRecord ConnectionNotEstablished Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sidekiq

I am working on Rails and from time to time I keep on getting error `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found`.

Before app was setup to use `good_job` for background process and it will always crash due to above error message. So I removed `good_job` and setup `sidekiq` to see if `good_job` is doing any thing strange. After setting sidekiq my app won't crash all the time, but when Sidekiq is run for first time and when it picks it's first job then again I get the same error message. Once Sidekiq retries then everything works fine, all other jobs after that works fine.

But there must be other root cause for this problem which I would like to solve. Our database is setup to write in `primary` and read from `replica`. This is how my `database.yml` looks like

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  username: postgres


development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: myapp_development
  primary_replica:
    <<: *default
    database: myapp_development
    replica: true
```

I have setup `DB_POOL` size to `20` for testing. And this is how my `sidekiq.yml` file looks like

```
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 5
:timeout: 10

:queues:
  # The default queue for all application jobs that don't have a specific queue.
  - default

  # The default queue for ActionMailer classes.
  - mailers

  # ActionMailbox queues. See `ActionMailbox.queues`.
  - action_mailbox_routing
  - action_mailbox_incineration

  # ActiveStorage queues. See `ActiveStorage.queues`.
  - active_storage_analysis
  - active_storage_purge
```

If I setup `concurrency: 1` in sidekiq then it never crash and everything works fine. My `Puma` is setup to use Max 5 thread.

When I was using `good_job` for background processing then I was also seeing these errors `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found for the 'reading' role.)`

I am running out of ideas how to solve this, looks like there is some problem related to `db connection pool`. Increasing connection pool size is not fixing the problem but setting `concurrency value to 1` for Sidekiq seems to fix the problem.

I think the problem may be related to Database rather than Sidekiq because those errors were coming before I move to Sidekiq. I just move to Sidekiq for testing to make sure it's not GoodJob creating the problem.

Here is status for connection pool

```
[1] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat 
=> {:size=>20, :connections=>0, :busy=>0, :dead=>0, :idle=>0, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}
```

Any suggestion for debugging this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a replica of your development database?

Comment: @max No replica of development db is not needed but it's good to setup similar to Production so I will know of any error. I also need to switch role between `read` and `write` while writing code so having replica DB is good in development.

Comment: When Rails boots it should connect to the database. Because you're using concurrency in Sidekiq (and I'm guessing it was the same problem with goodjob, I hate that gem), you have multiple threads which want to connect to the db at the same time. First thread will try to establish a connection pool, but a second one will fail with the error you're seeing.

Comment: Now I'm not sure why it wouldn't do it in development, but work in production.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel it don't work in production as well